# Add view to translucent linearlayout

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout, transparency

I'm having troubles getting my head around how to create add animation to a `LinearLayout` that is translucent. There are two views with opacity and a moving background (Google map if it is of importance). View1 is a `LinearLayout` and view2 is being added to view1. However when adding view2 it is seen through view1 (see left animation below).

[image]

Is there any way I can prevent this to achieve my animation correctly? (goal: see animation on the right) Keep in mind that the background is changing and is not a fixed picture.

Best regards
Rawa

Comment: Create a transparent LinearLayout the same height as View2, stacked horizontally atop View1 and containing View2, with View2's y-coordinate initially set to the height of the new LinearLayout, i.e. just outside the layout. Then animate View2 up until its y-coordinate is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine my comment may not have been entirely clear, so I put together a simple example to better explain and demonstrate. As I'm uncertain as to what your `View`s will be, I've left them rather generic, and set some hard-coded properties you will want to change.

`main.xml` layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stripes_diag" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00000000" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#88ffffff"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#88ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Animate"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    View view1, view2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
        view2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        view2.setY(view2.getHeight());
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view2, "y", 0);
        anim.setDuration(1500);
        anim.start();
    }
}
```

A look at the effect:

[image: effect sample]

Comment: Thanks, never though of that way. This solved my issue!